# I have a list and I only want things with values to show, neatly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a program in java for a school project. I'm using gui to make a sort of shopping center and I've made everything but I'm struggling with the cart window. I want it to list the items and the amount of items purchased. I also want it to show up neatly, without odd spaces, but the way I have it programmed has gaps if a certain item isn't bought. This is probably a really simple problem to resolve but i've only been coding for a few months and this is a self research project for school.

this is my code

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CartWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public static double total = 0, tax = 0, grandTotal = 0;
    public static int opalA = 0, rubyA = 0, diamondA = 0, swordA = 0, spearA = 0, scimitarA = 0, veilA = 0, topA = 0, sirwalA = 0, wheatA = 0, milkA = 0, oilA = 0;
    JLabel hah, opal, ruby, diamond, sword, spear, scimitar, veil, top, sirwal, wheat, milk, oil;
    JPanel slay;
    
    public CartWindow() {
        super("Cart");
        Container g = getContentPane();
        g.setLayout(null);
        
        tax = total * 0.13;
        grandTotal = total + tax; 
        
        slay = new JPanel();
        slay.setLayout(null);
        slay.setLocation(0,0);
        slay.setSize(400,600);
        g.add(slay);
        
        hah = new JLabel("Item   Price");
        hah.setSize(400, 40);
        hah.setLocation(0,0);
        slay.add(hah); 
        
        
        
        if (opalA > 0) {
            opal = new JLabel("Opal x" + opalA);
            opal.setSize(400,15);
            opal.setLocation(0,45);
            slay.add(opal);
        }
        if (rubyA > 0) {
            ruby = new JLabel("Ruby x" + rubyA);
            ruby.setSize(400,15);
            ruby.setLocation(0,60);
            slay.add(ruby);
        }
        if (diamondA > 0) {
            diamond = new JLabel("Diamond x" + diamondA);
            diamond.setSize(400,15);
            diamond.setLocation(0,75);
            slay.add(diamond);
        }
        if (spearA > 0) {
            spear = new JLabel("Spear x" + spearA);
            spear.setSize(400,15);
            spear.setLocation(0,90);
            slay.add(spear);
        }
        if (swordA > 0) {
            sword = new JLabel("Sword x" + swordA);
            sword.setSize(400,15);
            sword.setLocation(0,105);
            slay.add(sword);
        }
        if (scimitarA > 0) {
            scimitar = new JLabel("Scimitar x" + scimitarA);
            scimitar.setSize(400,15);
            scimitar.setLocation(0,120);
            slay.add(scimitar);
        }
        if (veilA > 0) {
            veil = new JLabel("Veil x" + veilA);
            veil.setSize(400,15);
            veil.setLocation(0,135);
            slay.add(veil);
        }
        if (topA > 0) {
            top = new JLabel("Top x" + topA);
            top.setSize(400,15);
            top.setLocation(0,155);
            slay.add(top);
        }
        if (sirwalA > 0) {
            sirwal = new JLabel("Sirwal x" + sirwalA);
            sirwal.setSize(400,15);
            sirwal.setLocation(0,170);
            slay.add(sirwal);
        }
        if (wheatA > 0) {
            wheat = new JLabel("Wheat x" + wheatA);
            wheat.setSize(400,15);
            wheat.setLocation(0,185);
            slay.add(wheat);
        }
        if (milkA > 0) {
            milk = new JLabel("Milk x" + milkA);
            milk.setSize(400,15);
            milk.setLocation(0,200);
            slay.add(milk);
        }
        if (oilA > 0) {
            oil = new JLabel("Oil x" + oilA);
            oil.setSize(400,15);
            oil.setLocation(0,215);
            slay.add(oil);
        }
        }
    
}
```

I want it so the values are listed neatly with no gaps, for example, if opalVal = 8 and spearVal = 9, id want it to look like this

```
Opal x8
Spear x9
```

but currently the output of my window looks like this

```
Opal x8


Spear x9
```

now i know why this happens, i coded the jpanels to show up at specific locations, but i want to fix it and i dont know how :(

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster.

Comment: A `JTable` would be more appropriate for a list of items and prices.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: Use a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) (preferably) or, if you don't mind messing about with custom renderers, a [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: Please post a working example showing the problem.  And you should not be extending `JFrame`.  Extend `JPanel` and add the panel to the `frame`.  All components should be placed in the panel or panels if you need more than one.  And do not use absolute positioning of components.  Use a proper layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use [gridpanel layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).
This will help aligning elements neatly into column and rows.
JTable is also a good option as has been commented.

The difference as I see it is whether you feed information to the JTable or insert graphical nodes into the gridPane, I guess it's a choice to be made.
There may be alternatives I'm not aware of, these are just suggestions.

Also you'd be well advised to learn the priciples of [map filter reduce](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/collections-in-java-tutorial#collections-api-algorithms).